# import csv file in gcs into Hubspot with HubSpot API

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, hubspot-api

I want to import csv file(Blob) in GCS into HubSpot with HubSpot API. I think HubSpot Import API accept only file object to post. I've already successed in importing local.CSV file by replaceing files=[('files',data)] to Local file path. Is it possible to upload GCS file into HubSpot ??
Thank you !

```
def importHubspot():
    storage_client  = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('..\gcredential.json')
　　
    bucket_name = 'hubspot-project'
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    
    ec_blob = bucket.blob("ec_latest_data.csv")
　　ec_blob = ec_blob.download_as_text(encoding="utf-8")

　　target_data = io.StringIO(ec_blob).getvalue()

　　datastring = json.dumps(data)

　　payload = {"importRequest": datastring}

　　response = requests.request("POST",post_url,data=payload,files=[('files',target_data)],headers=headers)
    print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
    print(response.status_code)
```

Error message above code

b'{"status":"error","message":"Unable to process JSON","correlationId":"1ccfd4f8-32fa-4584-9f70-c7154471dba8"}'
400